# Storing data in an array that is accessed by separate void c#

Tags: c#, arrays

i want to design a program that populates a 2D array in one void and accesses the results from another.  ie the array is at the program level not the void level.

Can anyone advise on the syntax?  in VBA its very simple, just private myarray() as variant at the top of the module.  I am struggling to adapt this.

Thanks for the help in advance!

```
namespace public_collection2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[,] info = new string[2, 2];
            info[0, 0] = "JN";
            info[0, 1] = "565";
            info[1, 0] = "GD";
            info[1, 1] = "700";

            foreach (var item in info)
            {
                if (IsNotDigits(item))
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
                }               
            }

        }

        bool IsNotDigits(string str)
        {
            foreach (char c in str)
            {
                if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                    return true;
            }

            return false;

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item in info)//info is not accessible
            {
                //pullout relevant number in 2d array
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: info is not accessible since it's declared inside a method and not on the class level. This means that it's only accessible on the method it's declared in.

Comment: can you advise of the syntax at the class level?  apologies i am a beginner.  I tried elevating the instantiation "string[,] info = new string[2, 2]; " but then the initial populating void didn't work.

Comment: thats working - unfortunate name choice with info for my array.  changed it and now no problems.  thanks for the help Zohar

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept an answer (since all current 5 answers  are basically the same, you can choose which one to accept) so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

```
string[,] info = new string[2, 2];
```

outside the method (but inside the class). Then it becomes an instance field (accessible from all methods) instead of a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment, `info` is only accessible in the scope it is declared.

Try this:

```
namespace public_collection2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {
        string[,] info = new string[2, 2];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            info[0, 0] = "JN";
            info[0, 1] = "565";
            info[1, 0] = "GD";
            info[1, 1] = "700";

            foreach (var item in info)
            {
                if (IsNotDigits(item))
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
                }               
            }

        }

        bool IsNotDigits(string str)
        {
            foreach (char c in str)
            {
                if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                    return true;
            }

            return false;

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item in info)//info is not accessible
            {
                //pullout relevant number in 2d array
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the info was only known in your method and now we moved it out of method but in class to be known in whole class

```
 namespace public_collection2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form

        {
            string[,] info = new string[2, 2];
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }


            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                info[0, 0] = "JN";
                info[0, 1] = "565";
                info[1, 0] = "GD";
                info[1, 1] = "700";

                foreach (var item in info)
                {
                    if (IsNotDigits(item))
                    {
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
                    }               
                }

            }

            bool IsNotDigits(string str)
            {
                foreach (char c in str)
                {
                    if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                        return true;
                }

                return false;

            }

            private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                foreach (var item in info)//info is not accessible
                {
                    //pullout relevant number in 2d array
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move variable declaration to global space just like VB

```
       public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string[,] info = new string[2, 2];

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }​
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant as the Array is declared in a private method and not at class level.

Declare the Array inside the class as an initialised field and you can access it anywhere.  If you just want it to be available in the class only and not outside of it, declare it as private.  Otherwise, leave it as public.

Comment: Never use public fields. Use a public property (and a private field if you need one) instead.

Comment: Erm...  Think you might be slightly mistaken here.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173118(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I didn't say it's impossible, but it *is* bad oop programming. read about [encapsulation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming))